# Random Freezes Windows 10 Ver 21H2

Tags: windows-10, freeze

My computer is new, custom built by a reliable computer shop:

```
Windows 10 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1415)
Motherboard: ROG STRIX B550-F GAMING (WI-FI)
BIOS: American Megatrends, ver 2423 09/10/2021
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X
Memory: Crucial DDR4-2401 (1200 Mhz) 16 GBytes x2
Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti 4GBytes GDDR5
SSD: Samsung 980 PRO 2TB
Power Supply: EVGA 500 BA, 80+ BRONZE 500W
Driver Updates: Complete
```

The Event Viewer is confusing. Here's the summary:

```
Warning 12/20/2021 2:17:20 PM   Kernel-EventTracing 1   Logging
Warning 12/20/2021 2:06:14 PM   DistributedCOM  10016   None
Warning 12/20/2021 2:06:14 PM   DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:05:24 PM   Kernel-EventTracing 3   Session
Warning 12/20/2021 2:05:24 PM   Kernel-EventTracing 4   Logging
Warning 12/20/2021 2:04:57 PM   DistributedCOM  10016   None
Warning 12/20/2021 2:04:57 PM   DistributedCOM  10016   None
Warning 12/20/2021 2:03:15 PM   DistributedCOM  10016   None
Warning 12/20/2021 2:03:12 PM   DistributedCOM  10016   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:03:01 PM   CertificateServicesClient-CertEnroll 86 None
Error   12/20/2021 2:02:59 PM   Application Error   1000    (100)
Warning 12/20/2021 2:02:57 PM   User Device Registration    360 None
Error   12/20/2021 2:02:37 PM   EnhancedStorage-EhStorTcgDrv    10  Driver
Warning 12/20/2021 2:02:30 PM   e2fexpress  27  None
Warning 12/20/2021 2:01:52 PM   WLAN-AutoConfig 10002   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:42 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:41 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:41 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:41 PM   DistributedCOM  10010   None
Error   12/20/2021 2:01:40 PM   Kernel-EventTracing 2   Session
```

I can provide more information as requested.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please tell us the symptoms and also why you think either the event log or system specs is relevant.

Comment: I apologize for my clumsy post. The event log may not be relevant. I can work for one hour sometimes three before symptoms begin. I work mostly in Photoshop and Dreamweaver. The symptoms are - the window in focus will stop responding but I can close it and go to other open windows. Eventually, all windows stop responding and I can't close any of them. Sometimes, I can go to Start and Shutdown but it does not shut down. Ctrl-Alt-Del doesn't work either. At that point, I can press the Reset button and reboot or press the Power button to force a shutdown. Thank you.

Comment: Download AutoRuns From Microsoft. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns.  On the Options menu tick *Hide Windows Entries* and *Hide Microsoft Entries*. Does this help.

Comment: This contains a lot of diagnostic information. It will take some time to study it and make adjustments. I'll let you know how this turns out. Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe that my problem is solved. There must have been some corruption in my Windows 10 installation. I upgraded to Windows 11 and have had no issues at all (except for some grumbling over some of the new and misplaced "features"!). Thank you very much for your help and putting me onto Autoruns. It provides lots of valuable information and is great to have in my toolbox. Happy Holidays!!

Answer (score 1):

> My computer is new, custom built by a reliable computer shop:
>
> Random freezes Windows 10 21H2

Make sure every driver and also BIOS (UEFI) are fully up to date (double check).

And then, return it to the shop who built it and (a) ask them to test hardware and (b) why is it freezing.

Windows 10 21H2 works reliably on a manufactured computer.

Comment: Problem solved. When I upgraded to Windows 11 the problem went away. There must have been some corruption in my Windows 10 installation.